# Vue3 Set List Item Different for Every Loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue3 I have a panel ("block that contains text") and I have a "level" logic that will show people how a loop of the panels. every panel have different value. Let say I'm asking for gender first; first panel will contain "male", other will contain "female". I want to save that values that user selected.

I have tried:

loop the component through "list"

```js
<component
  :list="levels"
  @chosen="activeLevel++"
  @configData="configData"
  :active-level="activeLevel"
  :is="BaseLevel"
></component>
```

list:

```js
const levels = [
  {
    heading: 'Choose a gender',
    text: ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'],
  },
  {
    heading: 'What is your activity leve?',
    text: ['Sedentary', 'Low to Moderate Activity', 'Active Lifestyle', 'Extreme Active'],
  }
]
```

component have a list item that contains:

```js
v-for="item in list[activeLevel].text"
```

and list again have an emit event:

```js
$emit('chosen')
```

"chosen" event does

```js
@chosen="activeLevel++"
```

My question is:
I want to emit one more event too when clicked,
(item = text that block contains)

```js
emitEvent('configData', item )
```

and listen it

```js
@configData="configData"
```

and configData should assign values to variables for each loop.
first loop will assign a variable named userGender, second will assign userAge etc..

Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: "and then ı want to make a formula with these informations but ı dont know its relevant" - this is the only request you made ? read your post again and form it better.
what do you want to achieve? and what do you want help with?

Comment: @AJZack I edited my question and I believe its more clear now. I will learn how to ask. This is my first question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can emit multiple values by using an object for example:

```
$emit('chosen', { chosen:true, configData:item})
```

and then in your component use one callback to call both `activeLevel++` and `configData`

```
<component
  :list="levels"
  @chosen="handleCallback"
  :active-level="activeLevel"
  :is="BaseLevel"
></component>
```

handleCallback:

```
function handleCallback(data){
   configData(data.configData);
   activeLevel++;
}
```

I hope you get the idea if you're using **one click** event use one callback handler and put your function calls there.